# What type of HTML, javascript, or web page source code would cause Adblock to not render a page when using Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, adblock

I'm experiencing an interesting issue with Google Chrome and Adblock (not Adblock Plus) preventing web pages from rendering altogether.

When I try to view this page http://inkthemes.com/wptheme/classicraft/ad/black-bmw-z4-red-leather-seats-convertible/

.. in Chrome with Adblock 2.36.2 enabled, the page just comes up blank. But, clicking on view source I can see the code fine. For this particular demo site the home page and the listing page all work fine. But every single content page comes up white. If I disable the extension then everything works fine.

I'm thinking somewhere there is some type of class or ID keyword that's triggering it, but would it cause the entire page to go blank (and not just the container for that class)?

Could it be related to the doctype? What could be causing this?

This is a link to the extension I'm using.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en

Comment: the word `ad` in the url.

Comment: that's not it. I've tried different url combinations in the dev environment. it happens even when mod_rewrite is off.

Comment: please show those examples.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `single-ad` class name that is present on the `body` tag.

Assuming this was intended by the author, it appears to be a naming collision with style declarations used by Adblock.

Otherwise there is some other reason that Adblock is interpreting the entire `body` as an advertisement and appending that class itself.